# Issue after upgrading flutter

Tags: flutter

I got this problem after upgrading Flutter and updating the SDK version in `pubspec.yalm` in my Flutter web project.

```
Error: The argument type 'void Function(TapDownDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragDownDetails)?'.
gesture_detector_builder.dart:186
- 'TapDownDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart' ('../../../dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart').
```

Comment: `flutter clean`

Comment: can you include your GestureDetector use case

Answer (score 0):

After debugging. I discovered that the problem was caused by a package named `flutter_math_fork`.
I searched `flutter_math_fork` in `pubspeck.lock` and found that my package `flutter_html` I listed in `pubspec.yaml` depend on it. I remove that package and it runs perfectly. Hope my steps help you well.